# Combinar en una sola columna los datos de varias columnas de un DataFrame

Tags: python, date, concat

tengo este DataFrame:

```
Resultad_=pd.DataFrame({"Año":(Datos["Año"]),"Mes":(Datos["Mes"]),"Dia":(Datos["Dia"]),"PP Manual (mm)":(Datos["Precipitacion [mm]"])})
```

Lo que quiero, es crear una columna llamada "Fecha" que me muestre los datos de la siguiente manera: Fecha= Año/Mes/Dia. Busqué información y encontré esta manera:

```
Resultad_["Fecha"]=Resultad_["Año"]+"/"+Resultad_["Mes"]+"/"+Resultad_["Dia"]
```

Sin embargo, me produce un error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types 
dtype ('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No has proporcionado un ejemplo de lo que contiene la variable `Datos`, pero a juzgar por cómo lo usas podría ser un diccionario como el siguiente:

```
Datos = {
    "Año": ["2018", "2018", "2018", "2019"],
    "Mes": ["11", "11", "12", "1"],
    "Dia": ["1", "30", "24", "5"],
    "Precipitacion [mm]": [100, 400, 500, 200]
}
```

Los valores de los años, meses y días, los he puesto como cadenas (podrían haber sido enteros, es decir, sin las comillas). He deducido que en tu caso son cadenas por el error que te sale, en el que menciona que los tipos que intentas combinar son `dtype('<U21')`, que corresponde al tipo Unicode, es decir, cadena.

Lo primero, comentar que para construir el DataFrame no necesitas acceder a cada campo del diccionario individualmente como has hecho, pues basta con:

```
Resultad_ = pd.DataFrame(Datos)
```

y ya pandas se ocupa de interpretar ese diccionario usando sus claves como nombres para las columnas y sus valores, si son listas como en este caso, como los valores de cada columna. Así el dataframe resultante es este:

```
    Año Dia Mes  PP Manual (mm)
0  2018   1  11             100
1  2018  30  11             400
2  2018  24  12             500
3  2019   5   1             200
```

Entiendo que lo que quieres es añadir una columna "Fecha" que combine lo que está separado en las tres columnas "Año", "Dia" y "Mes", y que lo has intentado con la operación `+`, esperando que Pandas concatenara cadenas.

Eso debería haber funcionado, y de hecho a mi me ha funcionado. El que no te funcione a ti me hace pensar que puede ser un problema con la versión de Python (yo he probado Python2), o con los datos de entrada `Datos`, que no sean como yo he supuesto.

En todo caso, aún si te funcionara, lo que tendrías en la columna "Fecha" seria en el fondo una cadena y no una fecha real. Pandas puede trabajar con columnas de tipo `datetime` que son muy útiles para un posterior procesamiento y para *time series*.

Para que la columna "Fecha" sea de tipo `datetime`, la conversión sería la siguiente:

```
Resultad_["Fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=Resultad_["Año"], 
                                         month=Resultad_["Mes"], 
                                         day=Resultad_["Dia"]))
```

Y el resultado sería:

```
    Año Dia Mes  PP Manual (mm)      Fecha
0  2018   1  11             100 2018-11-01
1  2018  30  11             400 2018-11-30
2  2018  24  12             500 2018-12-24
3  2019   5   1             200 2019-01-05
```

Aunque al volcar el dataframe lo veas como cadena, en realidad es un objeto de tipo `datetime`, que te permite hacer cosas como: `Resultad_.Fecha.dt.month` por ejemplo, para acceder al campo del mes, y así por ejemplo filtrar sólo las filas correspondientes a noviembre: `Resultad_[Resultad_.Fecha.dt.month == 11]`, etc.